# how to execute oracle procedure in jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I'm new in java jdbc. I try to run following oracle plsql query in java but I could'nt get result which I don't know how to execute. How I can run following sql code.How I can execute following procedure in jdbc. Please don't judge me I'm new in this

```
declare
  o_claim number;
  o_error number;
begin
  bss_ln.bss_claim(o_claim => o_claim,
                   o_error => o_error,
                   i_card => ?,
                   i_phone =>?,
                   i_product=>?);
end;
```

Comment: You need to use a `CallableStatement` these might be of use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html The first is the Java trail for using JDBC and the second is the API for CallableStatement.  I am sure a quick search of Stack Overflow will show plenty of examples

Comment: Could you please explain it widely. For instance how I can write plsql's variable inside of this procedure ?

Comment: I mean where will dissapear o_claim and o_error variable when I try to run bss_ln.bss_claim procedure. Is this not wrong to call only CallableStatement cstm = connection.prepareCall("{ bss_ln.bss_claim()}");

Comment: In this instance I cant provide more help then pointing you in the right direction, it has been a very very long time since I have used JDBC, I suggest search SO etc or the internet for tutorials as they will be able to show the latest syntax etc.  These are from sources I often use: 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc and  https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/

Comment: Thank you sir I found answer which I was needed thanks a lot

Comment: @MaksimVasilovich can you please post the answer you found using "add an answer" button then accept it for everyone to see and use if they encounter the same problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also inspire from the code samples (Chapter 6 to 9) of my book (no ads just sharing the code) @ http://download.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/jsp/pdf/Code_depot.zip.

Comment: This is a link answer. Please add some relevant code in your answer. Links die and then your answer will not be of much use.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectionManager mgr = ConnectionManager.getInstance();
OracleConnection conn = mgr.getConnection(connectionLabel);

CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call bss_ln.bss_claim(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }");
// prepare output params
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.NUMBER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.NUMBER);

// prepare input params
cstmt.setString(3, "input param");
cstmt.setString(4, "input param");
cstmt.setString(5, "input param");


cstmt.executeUpdate();

// get result
int o_claim = cstmt.getInt(1);
int o_error = cstmt.getInt(2);


// close cursor
cstmt.close();
```

Comment: Thanks sir your answer is correct.But unfortunately I can't upvote your question sorry for that